# Javascript: Getting up to an element without using an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="filter_dropdown_con">

<a class="trigger" href="0">all items</a>

<div class="dropcontainer">

<ul class="dropdownhidden">

<li><a href="1">first item</a></li>
<li><a href="2">second item</a></li>
<li><a href="3">third item</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

In my **JS** I use the following code **on the level of the li element:**

```
// get href of <a> tag of a clicked li tag
liahref=this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;

// remove domain path, ie. remove everything until the slash
liahref=liahref.substring(liahref.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

// put it into the href of the trigger a tag
trigger.href = liahref;
```

My question: In the last line ob the above JS, how can I address ONLY the trigger element of the div structure which contains the clicked li element? Because when I write "trigger.href", then ALL trigger-elements also in other div structures on the same page with similar drop down menus that include the "trigger" class get the value.

**** EDITED: ****

Background: The JS excerpt above is part of a major JS script to turn a select menu into a drop down menu with li elements. Here is the complete script:

http://jsfiddle.net/9dy7D/

Comment: How `trigger` is defined? Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: @Teemu:  I use a JS script to turn a select menu in a drop down menu with li elements. Here is the complete script:

http://jsfiddle.net/9dy7D/

Comment: @Teemu: The JS part cited in my post above starts on line 58 in the jsfiddle...

Comment: Could you possibly create a minimal/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demo? And, please, share that *minimal* code in your question.